# Beginner MySQL query with COUNT-"filter"

Tags: mysql, sql

I post this question here to get more clarity over my query while learning SQL
(The example is simplfied)

I have the following tables:

```
BookTable(bookID, isbn, title) // Holds every book, not the ammuont, just the writing 

CopyTable(copyID, bookID)      // Represent a physical copy

AuthorTable(authorID, fName, lName)    // Represents an author

WriteTable(authorID, bookID)   // Represents who wrote what
```

I want to select every author (Preferably like {authordID, fname, lname} ), if that author has a book written, which has more than 5 copies.

I am trying something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT authorID, fname, lname   // My final "output table"
FROM T_Author
WHERE authorID IN 
    SELECT authorID, bookID
    FROM T_Write
    WHERE bookID IN
        SELECT bookID, COUNT(*) AS count
        FROM T_Copy
        GROUP BY bookID // This part I doubt the most
        WHERE count > 5
```

So my idea is:

1. Select every BookID that appears more than 5 times in CopyTable
2. Select every author that wrote any of those books from WriteTable
3. Write out the name of the author with data from AuthorTable

I am not able to test this if it acutally works, but is this the "Right" way to think in this problem?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close.  Try this:

```
SELECT a.authorID, a.fname, a.lname   // My final "output table"
FROM T_Author a
WHERE a.authorID IN (SELECT w.authorID
                     FROM T_Write w
                     WHERE w.bookID IN (SELECT c.bookID
                                        FROM T_Copy c
                                        GROUP BY c.bookID // This part I doubt the most
                                        HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
                                       )
                    );
```

Notes:

- Subqueries need their own parentheses.
- For `IN`, the returned value has to *exactly* match what is being compared.  In general, you cannot return two columns.
- Use `HAVING` to filter *after* aggregation.
- `SELECT DISTINCT` is not needed in the outer query.  It just adds processing overhead.
- Use table aliases and qualified column names in any query that has more than one table reference.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up HAVING vs WHERE. So as you say "after aggregration", HAVING can be seen as "wait for result, then apply filter"?

Also thanks for the tips, I will correct my code accordingly :)

Comment: @viesa . . . If it helps for you to think of it that way, you can think of it that way.